# Create shortcut to directory via IShellLink

Tags: shortcut, windows-shell

Problem: I need to create shortcut to directory with custom icon in C# (there is no .NET API for that)

So far I've done: In my C# code I am quering IShellLink object (actually IShellLinkA), set it's target path via SetPath to `@"S:\my\myDirectory\"` (I also tried without last slash), set the icon via SetIconLocation to `@"S:\my\myDirectory\icon.ico, 0"`, than call `Save(@"S:\foo.lnk", true);` In case this is important, the `S:` is a network drive with write access

I get shortcut with proper icon under explorer, but after double click I get error message in polish "Windows is searching for file myDirectory, if you know the location use browse function". When I right click the shortcut and choose properties, I get `"Target type: file"`. When I manually create shortcut to directory under explorer, there is `"Target type: directory"`

I am surely missing something obvious, but I've spent last 30 minutes searching Google and MSDN for "shortcut/IShellLink to directory" and found nothing of use

**Edit:** Posting sources, as requested:

I am using IShellLink implementation from [this](http://msjogren.webhost4life.com/dotnet/eng/samples/dotnet_shelllink.asp) site, my code is very simple:

```
ShellShortcut shortcut = new ShellShortcut(@"S:\foo.lnk");
shortcut.Description = "Sample item";
shortcut.IconPath = @"S:\my\myDirectory\icon.ico";
shortcut.IconIndex = Convert.ToInt32(0);
shortcut.Path = @"S:\my\myDirectory\";
shortcut.WorkingDirectory = @"S:\my\myDirectory\";
shortcut.Save();
```

Comment: What you describe sounds OK, can you post the actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems I need new eyes :/ There was a hard to see typo (l instead of i) in path name...